# Need help installing plugin from source with make

Tags: install-from-source

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 x64 desktop DVD, and I have installed GIMP 2.6.12 from the Ubuntu Software Center. I need a plug-in for batch resizing of images, and found one. I downloaded the plug-in, extracted in my downloads folder. The read-me says to make and make install. I tried "make" via the terminal and I am getting an error. The plugin I am trying to install is http://www.alessandrofrancesconi.it/projects/bimp/. The full output in the terminal from my make command to the end is(sorry total noob for GNU/Linux and StackExchange here and don't know how to properly insert code):

---

```
aknewhope@jordandesktop:~/Downloads$ make
make: gimptool-2.0: Command not found
gcc -o ./bin/bimp -Wall -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-pointer-sign -Wno-parentheses
src/*.c src/manipulation-gui/*.c  -DGIMP_DISABLE_DEPRECATED 
src/bimp-gui.c:7:21: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
src/bimp-manipulations-gui.c:5:21: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
src/bimp-manipulations.c:7:21: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
src/bimp-operate.c:10:21: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
src/bimp.c:25:26: fatal error: libgimp/gimp.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
src/manipulation-gui/gui-changeformat.c:2:21: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
src/manipulation-gui/gui-color.c:1:21: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
src/manipulation-gui/gui-crop.c:1:21: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
src/manipulation-gui/gui-fliprotate.c:1:21: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
src/manipulation-gui/gui-rename.c:3:21: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
src/manipulation-gui/gui-resize.c:1:21: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
src/manipulation-gui/gui-sharp.c:1:21: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
src/manipulation-gui/gui-userdef.c:3:21: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
src/manipulation-gui/gui-watermark.c:3:21: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [make] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was, was that in the read-me, he states that "gimp-dev" package needs to be installed for plugin compilation for Gimp. I looked for that but it has a different name on ubuntu.packages.com(and Debian) called libgimp2.0-dev. Worked after installation of that. Contacted the developer on GitHub and he responded and will update in the future release. Thanks

Comment: I don't know the protocol here. Should he accept his answer to close the question?

Comment: I tried installing this library and the ones Welenofsky suggested but I still get this error.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you do not have the GTK+ development libraries installed. You may fix it by installing GTK+

try

```
sudo apt-get install libgtkmm-3.0-1 libgtk-3-dev
```

Comment: libgtkmm already was installed, and i installed libgtk-3-dev and restarted. same error.

Comment: The problem was, was that in the read-me, he states that "gimp-dev"(name from debian), needs to be installed. I looked for that but it has a different name on ubuntu.packages.com. libgimp2.0-dev. worked after installed that.

Answer (score 0):

You probably answered this long ago but in case you hit a problem like this in the future, you can use the search tool at packages.ubuntu.com to find out what package supplies a file.

Steve S.